# Let A be a ring and $J \subseteq M_n(A)$ be a bilateral ideal. Then exists a bilateral ideal $I \subseteq A$ such that $J=M_n(I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I've already proven that $J \subseteq M_n(I)$ by taking I={$a\in A / a = M_{11} $ for any $M \in J$}

I can't get the idea to show why a matrix $B$ in $M_n(I)$ should be in J. I can show that for every $B \in M_n(I)$ exists a matrix C(i,j) in J such that $B_{ij} = C(i,j)$, but the matrix C(i,j) is different for each $B_{ij}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the matrices $\Delta_{ij}$ with only one non-zero entry:
$$
\Delta_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \quad\mbox{if $i = j$}\\
0 & \quad\mbox{if $i \neq j$}
\end{array}\right.
$$
If $M$ is an element of your ideal $J$, then $\Delta_{ij}M \in J$, for every $i$ and $j$. But then $J$ must be $M_n(I)$ where $I$ comprises the members of $A$ that appear as coefficients in the matrices in $J$.